# windows10 somehow my pinned tiles disappeared. how do i get them back?

Tags: tiles

i have windows 10. I had tiles in the start and for some reason they disappeared. How do i get them back? I've been searching for hours. Can you help?

Comment: Did you try repining them from the all apps list?

Comment: Can you send snapshot of the screen, so i can easily understand what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem long time ago when I was getting initial W10 Mobile Insider builds. And you can't even pin them from swiping to All apps, the Pin to Start option seems disable.

I suggest you to do the following:

1. Try to **unpin the tiles and pin them again** from 'All apps' again. (if tiles are blank but present)
2. **Check for Updates** in **Windows Store** and **Phone Updates**. (Maybe the apps or system is getting updates)
3. **Restart your phone**. (I get my issues with disabled/blank tiles sorted out with this method)
4. Go to **Settings> Apps> Apps & features**. Select the apps with problem.
   You'll see **Advanced options** under app name, select it and **Reset**.
5. If the above issue is still un-resolved. **Try Uninstalling and Re-installing the app(s)**.

Else, the OS is running mad. :/

PS: *I recently discovered that after announcement of Microsoft accepting end for Windows 10 Mobile platform. Apps like truecaller are no longer available on store. Nor is it working. I recently un-bricked my phone and updated it from WP8.1>W10 Mobile 15254.527. Everything was working fine but truecaller (it is gone). Even, I was unable to login to the app. So, do check if app is available.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-pinning apps from the apps list? In the home screen, swipe left, tap and hold an app you need to pin to the start screen, select "Pin to start". Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

From the start screen, swipe from the right to the left to reveal the Apps List, and go to the app you want pinned on the start screen, long press on it, and select "Pin to Start"..!!

[image]

Repeat this process for all the apps you want to pin on your start screen